# How can one increase the inner margins/padding of a base plot in R?

Tags: r, plot

Using R's base plots, I know well how to control the margins between R plots and the outer margins of a panel of plots using, respectively:

```
par(mar=c(1,1,0,0))
par(oma=c(1,1,0,0))
```

What I am trying to learn is **a general way** to control the "inner margins" of a plot, which means: how can I increase/decrease the space between the axes and the plot content?

By "general way" I mean something that does not rely on simply manually adding/subtracting an offset to/from the min and max of the variable represented by a given axis. After all, such a solution could lead either to different padding between plots of a same plot panel depending on their scales and differences, or to the need of significant manual adjustments per plot within a plot panel.

Notice that my question is a direct analogous to [this other one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55521130/how-to-increase-the-inner-margin-of-a-ggplot-boxplot-in-facet-grid), but in my case I want to learn how to do it for base R plot instead of ggplot (it **does have to be base plot**).

Comment: I never noticed this question of mine had been closed. Unbelievable how SE has turned into a large quest for putting down questions/answers. This question was well focused enough to the point that it got a perfectly specific accepted answer whose provided knowledge I have used nearly every week in the 4 years since. I really wish SE went back to being a place where the energy is put into asking/answering, not on needlessly policing and downvoting every bit of perfectly fine questions. But oh well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As documented in `?plot.window`, the default is to extend the range of your data by 4% and use those as the plot limits.  You can't change the value 4% to another number, but you can set `xlim` and `ylim` explicitly to accomplish the same thing.

For example, if you want a `p=50%` extension instead, you want the lower limit for `x` to be `min(x) - p*diff(range(x))`, and a similar formula for the upper limit, and for `y`. But if you just use that as the first value in `xlim`, you'll 50%, followed by another 4%.  You could work around this, but using `xaxs = "i"` will use the exact spec.  Putting all of this together, here's an example:

```
x <- 1:10
y <- 5:14
p <- 0.5
plot(x, y, xlim = c(min(x) - p*diff(range(x)), max(x) + p*diff(range(x))), 
        xaxs = "i", 
        ylim = c(min(y) - p*diff(range(y)), max(y) + p*diff(range(y))), 
        yaxs = "i")
```

which produces this plot:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thanks you, that is exactly what I was looking for. I ended up arriving at that formulae myself, but the critical missing part was the `xaxs = 'i'`. It makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply adjust the ranges of your x and y plot limits:

```
x <- 1:10
y <- 1:10

# Before
plot(x, y)

# After
plot(x, y, xlim = range(x) + c(-1, 1), ylim = range(y) + c(-1, 1))
```

Output:

[image]
[image]

Comment: The problem with that is when you have plots in a panel, where `range(x)` can give different values and/or where the desired offset of `c(-1,1)` would lead to different padding in each plot depending on their scale differences. I need a solution that is more general than that. I will include this in the question

Comment: @Louis15 In this case, please provide a reproducible example, so people know exactly what kind of plot you are thinking about. By reproducible example, I mean code that people can run that will generate your described plots as a starting point.